# Using "preg_match" (or something similar) to match a "select" options

Tags: php, regex

i am trying to write validation that checks too see if the option picked matches the regex. There is 10 options, with only one of the options being wrong.

So far iv tried using if and else statements combined with "preg_match" and "$matches" but i cant seem to get it to work for select options. Here is my code and what iv been trying so far.

My Select options on form:

```html
<h3>Standard</h3>
<label for="Adu">Adults</label>
  <span class="error">* <?php echo $staErr;?></span>
  <select name="seats[STA]" id="seatsSTA">
    <option value="0">Choose one from below</option>
    <option value="1">1xTicket</option>
    <option value="2">2xTicket</option>
    <option value="3">3xTicket</option>
    <option value="4">4xTicket</option>
    <option value="5">5xTicket</option>
    <option value="6">6xTicket</option>
    <option value="7">7xTicket</option>
    <option value="8">8xTicket</option>
    <option value="9">9xTicket</option>
            </select>
```

My attempt at the regex:

```php
$staErr = "";
$seatsSTA = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["seatsSTA"])) {
    $staErr = "no match";
  } else {
    $seatsSTA = test_input($_POST["seatsSTA"]);
    // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
    if (preg_match("/\b1xTICKET\b/i",$seatsSTA)) {
      $staErr = "matches";
    }
  }
}
```

It should Echo "matches" if any of the tickets options are selected (1xTicket, 2xTicket,...) and it should echo "no match" if any other option is picked (in this case it will only be "Choose one from below").

Comment: `seats[STA]` is different than `["seatsSTA"]`. Why did you use brackets?

Comment: When you post the select with form action, then the `$_POST["seats"]["STA"]` possible values are `1`-`9` not `1xTicket` to `9xTicket` because you get the selected option value, not the option tag contained content.

Comment: Also, `$_POST["seats"]["STA"]` will contain the `value` so `1`, `2`, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your input name is incorrect. You are using `seats[STA]` in the form and `seatsSTA` in PHP.

Second  Your pattern is matching only for number 1 when it should match all numbers from 1-9 like this `/\b[1-9]xTICKET\b/i`

Comment: OMG i am so dumb.... i cant believe i forgot to change the naming of it... i thought i did but looks like i changed the ID instead of name... and i was wondering why it would never read my input. cheers